# Connecting mongodb replicaset from nodejs, to use replicaset as failover

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have following architecture,

```
             Node js server
                  |
             Load Balancer
                  |
    ______________________________
   |              |               |
Mongodb         mongodb        mongodb
replicaSet1     replicaSet2    replicaSet3
```

I am using [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/) module. As I am using load balance, what configurations do I need at nodejs level or load balancer level so if any mongodb instance goes down, the nodejs can still get data.

**If there is no use of loadbalancer, here I can remove it. The scenario is only for fault tollerance**

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer.
There is no need of hardware load balancer, Just need minor change in application.

Here is what I have to change in connection url.

```
var url="mongodb://"
    + "localhost:3000,"
    + "localhost:3001,"
    + "localhost:3003"
    + "/testDB?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred";
```

list all mongodb instances in url separated by comma, add parameter `replicaSet=replisetName`, `readPreference=secondaryPreferred` *(This is optional, and [Not recommended](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#counter-indications))*.

[Here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_1and2_2.html) is reference.